# Success: Trying to end Path at a certain point

Tags: path, 2d-games, game-maker-studio-1.4

EDIT: I have since implemented the feature and it looks great in my personal opinion, I have added a link to my game dev's instagram which has a preview video of the feature. **Please have a look, and like the post if you like what you see because another opinion is valuable to me**

https://www.instagram.com/p/CBlAlgfpIT_/?igshid=v8ahisp6nfy9

---

I'm wondering if anyone could please help me. I have a camera object which is set to View0 in a room 3416x1920 and then camera view set to 854x480. In this specific room I have 3 options pages I want the user to navigate to by using Paths and to stop once arrived on correct page (I have a system setup for navigation already, just needing help with Paths). How would I make the Path stop without resetting and going back to start point, **at the moment it plays the Path and doesn't stop when hits end it'll just loop back to start.**

I have included a photo diagram of what I'm trying to do, as well as a screenshot of my current Paths setup. Any help is much appreciated thanks.